# jqGrid not showing json data in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

jqGrid is not showing json data fetched from MVC controller, it also has a *emptyrecords* label which is also not visible in this case. Here is my jQuery code-

```
$(function () {
            $("#JQGrid1").jqGrid({
                url: "/CertificateDetails/GetCertificateDetails",
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'Get',
                colNames: ['Name', 'Issuer', 'Location', 'Private Key[Yes/No]'],
                //data: dataArray,
                colModel: [
                   {
                       key: false,
                       name: 'Name',
                       index: 'Name',
                       editable: false
                   },
                   {
                       key: false,
                       name: 'Issuer',
                       index: 'Issuer',
                       editable: false
                   },
                   {
                       key: false,
                       name: 'Location',
                       index: 'Location',
                       editable: false
                   },
                   {
                       key: false,
                       name: 'HasPrivateKey',
                       index: 'HasPrivateKey',
                       editable: false
                   }
                ],
                height: '100%',
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: "Certificate Details",
                emptyrecords: "No record to display!!"
            });
        });
```

Controller code:

```
CertDetails cd = new CertDetails();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        //
        // GET: /CertificateDetails/
        public ActionResult GetCertificateDetails()
        {
            var stores = new Dictionary<StoreName, string>()
                {
                        {StoreName.My, "Personal"},
                        {StoreName.Root, "Trusted roots"},
                        {StoreName.TrustedPublisher, "Trusted publishers"},
                        {StoreName.AddressBook, "Address Book"},
                        {StoreName.AuthRoot, "Auth Root"},
                        {StoreName.CertificateAuthority, "Certificate authority"},
                        {StoreName.Disallowed, "Disallowed"},
                        {StoreName.TrustedPeople, "Trusted people"}
                // and so on
                }.Select(s => new { store = new X509Store(s.Key, StoreLocation.LocalMachine), location = s.Value }).ToArray();

            foreach (var store in stores)
                store.store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly); // open each store

            var list = stores.SelectMany(s => s.store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>()
                .Select(mCert => new CertDetails
                {
                    HasPrivateKey = mCert.HasPrivateKey ? "Yes" : "No",
                    Name = mCert.FriendlyName != "" ? mCert.FriendlyName : "Unavailable",
                    Location = s.location,
                    Issuer = mCert.Issuer
                })).ToList();

            return Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here is the data returned from controller action method-

```
[{"Name":"Unavailable","HasPrivateKey":"Yes","Location":"Personal","Issuer":"CN=Dell Issuing Certificate Authority 302, OU=MS PKI, O=Dell Inc."},{"Name":"IIS Express Development Certificate","HasPrivateKey":"Yes","Location":"Personal","Issuer":"CN=localhost"}]
```

I'm getting the data in JSON format from the controller but neither jqGrid shows any data nor it shows empty records label. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Could you append your question with the test data returned from the server? You can use Developer Tools of Chrome/IE/Firefox to see exact HTTP response.

Comment: @Oleg, I'm using jQuery.jqGrid available for free on nuget and the version is 4.4.4. I'm getting the data in var list but it is not showing up in grid.

Comment: I recommend you uninstall retro version 4.4.4, which is dead since very long time and install [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid) NuGet package in the current version: 4.14.1. What about the test JSON data? By the way I'd recommend you to remove unneeded  `key: false,editable: false` and `index` properties from `colModel` and to add jqGrid options `loadonce: true, forceClientSorting: true`

Comment: @Oleg, I've added the data in the question body returned by action method.

Comment: Do you tried with free jqGrid 4.14.1? Is the problem still exist? JSFiddle allows to use Echo service (`url: "/echo/json/"`) to simulate server response. One have to send the `json` parameter to the server with the data, which the server should return. One can use `postData: { json: ...}` to do this. Echo service require to use HTTP POST. Such minimal changing of your code you can see on the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/3j7dz8aa/2/, which works. You can use some more features. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/3j7dz8aa/3/. In any way I see no problem with JSON data which you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try jQuery DataTable plugin instead, like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myGrid").dataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/CertificateDetails/GetCertificateDetails",
                "dataSrc": ""
            },
            "columns": [{
                "data": "Name"
            }, {
                "data": "Location"
            }, {
                "data": "Issuer"
            }, {
                "data": "HasPrivateKey"
            }]

        });
    });

<table id="myGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr style="text-align:left;">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Issuer</th>
            <th>HasPrivateKey?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
      </table>
```

Don't forget to add the references-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```